# How can I convert a YYYYMMDD string to date?

Tags: string, datetime, tableau-desktop

In my database through Athena, I have a dt (date) field that returns YYYYMMDD, however, when I try to convert it into a date, I get an error message.

Ex. 20211218

I would like to turn that into 12-18-2021

Is there a calculation in Tableau that could convert it to a date field? I don't have DATEPARSE available.

Answer (score 0):

The problem can be solved as follows, with the `dt` field being the value returned from the database. I assumed the `dt` string is *YYYYMMDD* so you can follow the solution. String methods are used to solve this problem <sup>[1]</sup>.

```
LEFT(dt,4) + "-" + LEFT(MID(dt, 5), 2) + "-" + RIGHT(dt, 2)
```

###### Step-1

The `LEFT(dt, 4)` function returns the first 4 characters in the `dt` string. This method returns the following result: *YYYY*

###### Step-2

The `MID(dt,5)` method splits the `dt` string from the fifth character to the end; *MMDD*. The `LEFT("MMDD", 2)` method is used to get the 2 characters from the left side of the new string expression: *MM*

###### Step-3

The `RIGHT(dt, 2)` method returns the last two characters of the `dt` string: *DD*

###### Step-4

After combining the results, the following string expression is obtained: *YYYY-MM-DD*

---

<sup>1 - [String Functions](https://help.tableau.com/current/pro/desktop/en-us/functions_functions_string.htm)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

The DATEPARSE function will convert yyyyMMdd to date as below:

```
DATEPARSE('yyyyMMdd',str([EXAMPLE_DATE]))
```

This seems to be the best method currently.
It can take a bit of tweaking to get the 'yyyyMMdd' part right as it must match your input date format. But it should work.